# WebP fast compression

Tags: android, webp

I would like to use WebP format because it compresses (encodes) images very good (good quality and small size)

But on Android the next method to compress bitmap to WebP works quite slow

130-140 ms for bitmap with 640x360 resolution on device with Snapdragon 625

```
val stream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.WEBP, 40, stream)
val webpBytes = stream.toByteArray()
```

Is there any faster method on Android to convert `Bitmap` or raw frame from camera (`NV12`) to compressed WebP image? Mb a third-party library?

I tried OpenCV and it works a little faster (100-107) but still it's not enough

```
MatOfInt params = new MatOfInt(Imgcodecs.IMWRITE_WEBP_QUALITY, 10);
MatOfByte matOfByte = new MatOfByte();
Imgcodecs.imencode(".webp", mat, matOfByte, params);
byte[] webpBytes = matOfByte.toArray();
```